# If a group has order $2p^a$ where p is an odd prime and a $\geq$ 1, then G has a proper, nontrivial normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have this problem and I'm stuck. I only know that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ but don't know how to continue from there.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Sylow $p$-group has index 2, so it has to be normal.

Comment: Thank you. But it should applies to any odd prime p. I just changed the title, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, it is not difficult to show that any subgroup of index 2 is a normal subgroup.